# copy 1 file to multiple with names and input from another file

Tags: python, operating-system, command

I want to read names.txt which containes 40/50 names and have ECT.docx

want to copy ECT.docx to multiple names from name.txt.

i have made following command in Python, please correct its not working.

```
import os
file=open('names.txt')
for nam in file.readlines():
    cmd='copy ECT.docx ' + nam +'.doc'
```

Comment: cmd is just a string, you have to execute it.  To execute cmd, you can use  https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Call the [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#module-shutil) module's `copyfile()` function to actually copy the file instead of creating a `cmd` string.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use python write file with w+, but I provided example in your preference. I used With block to handle closing the file.

```html
import os
import subprocess
with open("names.txt") as f:
    for nam in f.readlines():
        myCmd='cmd /c copy ECT.docx ' + nam +'.doc'
        subprocess.call(myCmd)
```